# Http GET request between Amazon EC2 servers

Tags: php, http, amazon-ec2

We have two AWS EC2 instances and from the first server using PHP I am making a request to the second server like this: `file_get_contents('https://somedomain.com/api/feed/obj/1234')`. It tries to connect but just hangs.

Using `wget` in the terminal I get:

```
$ wget -dv https://somedomain.com/api/feed/obj/1234
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.17.1 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/abc/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
converted 'https://somedomain.com/api/feed/obj/1234' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'https://somedomain.com/api/feed/obj/1234' (UTF-8)
--2021-06-01 11:08:01--  https://somedomain.com/api/feed/obj/1234
Resolving somedomain.com (somedomain.com)... vv.xx.yy.zz
Caching somedomain.com => vv.xx.yy.zz
Connecting to somedomain.com (somedomain.com)|vv.xx.yy.zz|:443...
```

I guess it has something to do with internal/external ip's.

Comment: What error do you get, once it is done “hanging” (presumably that’s not going on for all eternity, but will terminate at some point.) Have you checked access and error logs of the other server yet, to see if that yields any useful error information?

Comment: I can't find anything in the logs on the 2nd server.
I get this after a few minutes: 

Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Releasing 0x000055baf6d881e0 (new refcount 1).
Retrying.

And it will just keep retrying.

Comment: Okay, then that might at least serve as an indicator, that the request never actually made it that far. Did you try using cURL instead of file_get_contents, and then check if curl_error has anything to say afterwards?

Comment: With curl:
Failed to connect to somedomain.com port 443: Connection timed out

Comment: Might be local firewall rules not letting the request pass through. Did wget on the console actually get you any result, or did that also just end in a timeout after it said it was `Connecting to …`?